# Sort object keys with each and handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I would like to sort objects keys with each:
test1, test4, test3 => test1, test3, test4
...

My json:

```
"tests": {
    "chapter1": {
        "test1": 5,
        "test4": 8,
        "test3": 3
    },
    "chapter2": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test5": 14,
        "test3": 12
     }
}
```

My handlebars code:

```
{{#each tests}}
    <h1>{{@key}}</h1>
    <ul>{{#eachSorted this}}<li>{{this}}</li>{{/eachSorted}}</ul>
{{/each}}
```

I tried but does not work:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachSorted', function(context, options) {
    var ret = ""
    Object.keys(context).sort().forEach(function(key) {
        ret = ret + options.fn({key: key, value: context[key]})
    })
    return ret
})
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: It is 5,3,8 and 1,12,14 with my handlebars code in an html list.

Comment: Note that the title says 'Sort array...' but instead you wanna sort an object keys with their values.

Comment: @NicoDiz You are rigth. I edited my post.

Comment: Great!   Did my answer worked?

Comment: I marked the first answer because that was exactly what I was looking for. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are rendering the whole object instead of the value. Try this:

```
{{#each tests}}
    <h1>{{@key}}</h1>
    <ul>{{#eachSorted this}}<li>{{this.value}}</li>{{/eachSorted}}</ul>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this does not sort my objects by the key value.

Comment: it will. the helper method you wrote will work. you just need to change the way you are accessing the sorted values.

Comment: Omg, you are right. sry! When I want to create a second table with same sorting but with key then I get no output with key.value

Comment: if you want to render the key use `{{this.key}}'

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `eachSorted` function with this:

```js
var tests = {
    "chapter1": {
        "test1": 5,
        "test4": 8,
        "test3": 3
    },
    "chapter2": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test5": 14,
        "test3": 12
     }
};

function eachSorted(context) {
    var ret = {};
 Object.keys(context)
  .sort()
  .forEach(function(key) {
   ret[key] = context[key];
    });
    return ret;
}


console.log(eachSorted(tests.chapter1));
```

Also, in your JSON `tests` is an object. Are you sure you can apply `each` to an object? Maybe you should use an array. You can change the JSON or you can make a registerHelper that creates an array from the values. Use: `Object.values(tests)`.
Hope it helps.